# Making a list in a list: making lists of words from words in a word list

Tags: python, list

I have a word list of words like so:

```
wordlist = ['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'store', '<s>', 'i', "'d", 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'a', 'fancy', 'restaurant','<s>']
```

I want to make a list of sentences:
this is the code I'm using

```
sentence = []
start = []
end = []

wordlist = [word.replace('.','<s>') for word in wordlist]

for word in wordlist:
    end = word['<s>']


for word in wordlist:
    sentence = word[0][end]
    sentence.append([])
```

I'm trying to get a list like this:
`sentence=[['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'store', '<s>'], ['i', "'d", 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'a', 'fancy', 'restaurant','<s>], ...etc]`

my idea is marking the end of a sentence with '' and telling my sentence list to create a new list after ''. anything will help, thank you.

Comment: Your given information is not a list, is one string in a list? Or a list with a item for every word? Please properly format/describe the given information

Comment: it is a list, i updated my question! thank you

Comment: Btw, your list is not properly closed and missing a quote, `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to replace `'<s>'` strings with `'.'` to keep track of when sentences end. If you want to end sentences at `'<s>'`, you can just check for these each time you add a word to your current sentence, like so:

```
sentences = []
current_sentence = []

for word in wordlist:
    current_sentence.append(word)
    if word == '<s>':
        sentences.append(current_sentence)
        current_sentence = []

print(sentences)
```

Here, I replaced your `sentence` list with `sentences`. This will keep track of all of the sentences that you make from your word list. `current_sentence` will keep track of all of the words in your current sentence. When you reach a `'<s>'`, this code adds your current sentence list to `sentences`, then resets `current_sentence` to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `iter` from `wordlist` and then use a `while` loop with `try/except` to iterate and create your sublists that will be appended to your final list.

```
a = iter(wordlist)
res = []
temp = []

while True:
    try:
        b = next(a)
        if b != '<s>':
            temp.append(b)
        else:
            temp.append(b)
            res.append(temp)
            temp = []

    except StopIteration:
        break

print(res)
# [['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'store', '<s>'], ['i', "'d", 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'a', 'fancy', 'restaurant', '<s>']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Append your results to a list and reset it after you have found your end, in this case is `<s>`

```
wordlist = ['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'store', '<s>', 'i', "'d", 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'a', 'fancy', 'restaurant','<s>']
results = []
result = []

for word in wordlist:
    if word == '<s>':
        result.append(word)
        results.append(result)
        result = []
    else:
        result.append(word)
```

Final output in `results`:

```
[['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'store', '<s>'],
 ['i', "'d", 'like', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'a', 'fancy', 'restaurant', '<s>']]
```